# Send an iMessage from a Linux server?

Tags: php, iphone, linux, sms, imessage

Is there any way to send an iMessage from a Linux server to an iPhone?

Obviously... with most traditional SMS plans, you can always send a message to something like 2125551212@txt.att.net and receive it on the phone.

Does an equivalent exist for iMessage?

Comment: It might be helpful to explain, or at least link to, what iMessage is.

Comment: I'm not sure of the specific reason why you are trying to use iMessage, but have you considered push notifications instead? Unlike SMS, iMessage and push notifications both don't offer any special perks you may be after, such as collecting donations. Really, the only difference between push notifications and iMessage is your ability to include a photo/video in the body of the message. You could display it in the app when the user opens the notification.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, we're trying to deliver a link only to iPhone users... We'll probably just go with the email -> sms old school way, but since our target was iPhones specifically, we figured it'd be pretty sweet to just use iMessage instead of trying to get users to put in their longform sms email address.

Answer (score 10):

No, iMessage doesn't work like traditional SMS.

There's no public API available for the protocol, either.